# Does Magento 2 launch all RabbitMQ consumers only by cron?

Tags: cron, rabbitmq, magento2

I am very surprised by the fact that I found that it seems that Magento 2 launches all RabbitMQ consumers only by cron.

I expected to see RabbitMQ as a separate application that accepts tasks from PHP / Magento code as input.

And later, RebbitMQ itself decides at what time to call the Magento 2 API and give some task for processing.

Can anyone clarify this question for me?

I expected to see RabbitMQ as a separate application that runs in a separate process and only receives tasks for execution and then calls the Magento API to process the task.

I had a better opinion of Magento 2 architects. But perhaps this is the only possible way to do it. Or not?

Comment: Something similar was already asked on https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324970. If the answers on linked question does not answer your question, you could consider asking your question on https://magento.stackexchange.com as questions asking how to configure or deploy web applications are off-topic on Stack Overflow.